# Is there some way to specify if template param of function is specific template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I will explain my question based on following example:

```cpp
template <typename Param1, typename Param2>
class foo1
{
  void lol();
};

template <typename Param1, typename Param2>
class foo2
{
  void lol();
};

////////////////////////// FIRST OPTION //////////////////////////

template <typename Param1, typename Param2>
void func(foo1<Param1, Param2> a)
{
  a.lol();
  a.lol();
}

template <typename Param1, typename Param2>
void func(foo2<Param1, Param2> a)
{
  a.lol();
}

////////////////////////// SECOND OPTION //////////////////////////

template <typename Foo_>
void func(Foo_ a)
{
  a.lol();
  a.lol();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

My goal is to write two overloads of `func` - for `foo1` and `foo2`.
The `FIRST OPTION` works fine, but I don't like that I have to write template parameters for `func` that are not used in it.
Is there some way to avoid writing template parameters in signature of `func`?

I thought of writing something like this `SECOND OPTION`, but the problem is that overloads do different things.

Comment: *"I don't like that I have to write template parameters for func that are not used in it"* - except they *are* used. They're what drives the `fooN` template to conclude to a specific type for `a`. What is it exactly that is unattractive, the clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template parameters *are* used. Without them, `foo1` and `foo2` are just class templates and not a classes.

A simple way to minimize the typing would be to use template parameter packs:

```cpp
template<class... T>
void func(foo1<T...> a) {
    a.lol();
    a.lol();
}

template<class... T>
void func(foo2<T...> a) {
    a.lol();
}
```

---

If you need this check a lot, you can create `concept`s (since C++20):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// concept for foo1:
template <class T> struct is_foo1 : std::false_type {};
template <class P1, class P2> struct is_foo1<foo1<P1, P2>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> concept Foo1Type = is_foo1<T>::value;

// concept for foo2:
template <class T> struct is_foo2 : std::false_type {};
template <class P1, class P2> struct is_foo2<foo2<P1, P2>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> concept Foo2Type = is_foo2<T>::value;
```

Then the `func` overloads become simpler:

```
void func(Foo1Type auto a) {    
    a.lol();
    a.lol();
}

void func(Foo2Type auto a) {    
    a.lol();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KxedMEdnT)